# What would a hydrogen balloon find easiest to lift?

Tags: mass, density, buoyancy

So I was reading a book, and came across a statement that out of objects like $1$ kg of steel, $1$ kg of water and $1$ kg of feathers, a hydrogen balloon would find it easier to lift up with the feathers. I am guessing it is due to the fact that feathers are the least dense of the given substances. Am I right in thinking so. I mainly got this doubt, because the masses of all three substances are same, and so, it would require same force.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends hugely whether its 1kg mass or weight.

Assuming it was mass, let the Volume of Steel, Water & Feathers be $V_S, V_W$ and $V_F$
Now, we know that $V_F > V_W > V_S$.
We also know that the buoyant force felt by each due to the weight of the atmosphere is proportional to their Volumes.
Volumes $V_F > V_W > V_S$ => Buoyant forces $F_F > F_W > F_S$.

And so, the weight of each will be $1g$ - their respective buoyant forces.

As the buoyant force felt by the feathers will be maximum, it will be lighter than the others.